# Necessary and sufficient condition for all the eigenvalues of a real matrix to be non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

According to wikipedia, a totally positive matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_positive_matrix) always have non-negative eigenvalues. But, is it necessary for a matrix to be totally positive to have non-negative eigenvalues?

I'm looking for the necessary and sufficient condition for a real square matrix (not necessarily symmetric) to have non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: You may want to look up diagonal dominance and Gershgorin's circle theorems.

Comment: @bcf : Thank you. Gershgorin's circle theorem looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not necessary. Just consider the matrix 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1\\
-1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
which is not totally positive but it is still has non-negative eigenvalues $\{1,3\}.$

Comment: Is there any necessary condition then?

Comment: Yes, you can get many necessary conditions. e.g. for a square matrix $A,$ $det(A)\geq 0$ or $Tr(A) \geq 0$ are necessary conditions (although these are not sufficient)