# What is a necessary and sufficient condition for all the eigenvalues of a non-symmetric matrix to be positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a real but not symmetric matrix $A$. To test if the matrix has positive eigenvalues, I've learnt from this forum that a symmetric matrix will be given by $B=A+A^T$. If all the eigenvalues of $B$ are positive, then it follows that A also has all the eigenvalues positive. So this is a sufficient condition.

For example, consider

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

It so happens that $B$ has one negative eigenvalue. Whereas $A$ has both positive eigenvalues. So what is a necessary (and sufficient) condition that $A$ has all positive eigenvalues?

Looking at Gershgorin's theorem , further rises the possibility of complex eigenvalues.

References:

1. [Tests for positive definiteness for nonsymmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387192/tests-for-positive-definiteness-for-nonsymmetric-matrices.%5C)
2. p.322,Linear Algebra and its Applications, Gilbert Strang.
3. [Necessary and sufficient condition for all the eigenvalues of a real matrix to be non-negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810457/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-all-the-eigenvalues-of-a-real-matrix-to-b)

Comment: A non-symmetric matrix may have complex eigenvalues. Do you want their real parts to be positive?

Comment: A search for 'Lyapunov equation' might be helpful.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I want all the  Eigen Values to be real

Comment: @TilakMallikarjun That is why symmetry is nice. It does ensure that the eigenvalues are real.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I am having a non-symmetric matrix, whose sign of Eigen values determine the nature of  a phenomena. So I want to know if at all it is possible with the methods in Linear algebra to get an idea of the same without actually solving for Eigen values.

Comment: @TilakMallikarjun Signs or signs of real parts?

Comment: we want to check if  all the Eigen values are positive real for a given real non-symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is false: take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ 
then  $A+ A^T=2I_2$ has his eigenvalues positive whereas eigenvalues of $A$ are $1 \pm i$ not even real...

Comment: I agree. The proposition here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387192/tests-for-positive-definiteness-for-nonsymmetric-matrices.%5C disregards the possibility of complex Eigen values.

Comment: Also it is  falsely stated that positive Eigen values are possible if and only if A+A' is positive definite. It would be helpful in future if  someone with a reputation of 50 or more can post a comment in that page https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387192/tests-for-positive-definiteness-for-nonsymmetric-matrices.%5C by giving the counter  examples provided by me and Robien1